# EventBus(android)

Tags: android, eventbus

Возникли проблемы с EventBus

В 1-м фрагменте отправляю пост

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new TestString("123"));
```

Во 2-м фрагменте регистрирую EventBus(в методе onStart)

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

И определяю метод для чтения переданных параметров(во 2-м фрагменте)

```
@Subscribe
public void onEvent(TestString event){
    tx4.setText(event.getS());
}
```

В ответ мне приходит:

> D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class
>   com.example.user_android.a366.Model.TestString
>
> D/EventBus: No
>   subscribers registered for event class
>   org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent

Comment: А где вызывается `register`? И не вызывается ли `unregister`? Оба фрагмента созданы и находятся в одном активити? Я бы добавил логи перед регистрацией, дабы удостовериться что она вызывается.

Comment: register вызывается в методе 2го фрагмента(который принимает данные) onStart()

Comment: unregister вызывается в методе onDestroy(2го фрагмента,которы принимает)

Comment: Оба фрагмента находятся в одном активити и переход между ними осуществляется при помощи replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас отправка происходит из одного фрагмента, а получить ивент вы хотите в другом, еще не созданном на момент отправки. Так не получится.
Если хотите передать данные в создаваемый фрагмент, то используйте `setArguments` при создании фрагмента.
А если хотите получать ивенты через EventBus, то подписчики должны быть подписаны до отправки ивента. Точнее только подписанные на момент отправки получат ивенты, в этом и суть либы.
И еще я бы использовал для подписки и отписки парные методы, например, `onStart` и `onStop`. А лучше `onResume` и `onPause`.

Comment: То есть, для подписки я должен указывать что-то вроде EventBus.getDefault().register(ListFragment.class);

Comment: Нет, я имею в виду что в вашем случае подписка не подходит по тому что фрагменты отображаются в разное время. По идее этот механизм создан для того чтобы передавать ивенты их одной части приложения в другую, но существующую одновременно с источником ивента. А для передачи данных в создаваемый фрагмент надо использовать `setArguments`, по тому что когда вы кидаете ивент, этого фрагмента не существует, и уж точно у него еще не вызывался onStart, где вы регистрируете слушателя событий.

Comment: Понял, благодарю